# Alpakka Cassandra Flow Usage

Tags: akka-stream, alpakka

I am reading the documentation of Alpakka Cassandra [here](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/cassandra.html)

It makes it very easy to use Cassandra as a source and a sink. but what about flow usage.

By flow usage I mean is that I am not using Cassandra as a source or a sink. but to Lookup Data.

is that possible using Alpakka? or should I have to write the Cassandra jdbc code in a flow myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Sink.** If you check Alpakka's [source code](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/cassandra/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/cassandra/scaladsl/CassandraSink.scala), you'll find that the Sink is constructed as follows

```
Flow[T]
      .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism)(t ⇒ session.executeAsync(statementBinder(t, statement)).asScala())
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
```

if you only need a passing flow, you can always trim out the `Sink.ignore` part, and you'll have

```
Flow[T]
          .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism)(t ⇒ session.executeAsync(statementBinder(t, statement)).asScala())
```

You will only need to expose the Guava futures converter, which is currently package private in Alpakka.

**2) Source.** You can always obtain a `Flow` from a `Source` by doing `.flatMapConcat(x => CassandraSource(...)`)